# Track Facebook App (iOS or Android or whatever) visits on my webpage

Tags: android, ios, facebook

Is there anyway to track visits that come from facebook app ?

I tried php http_referer but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do it unless Facebook decides to add a referrer when it sends the URL out of the app and the users' OSs and browsers receive it and pass it along.  Referring URLs are passed to the server by the browser and, due to increasing privacy concerns, are slowing disappearing in general.

If you're curious about where traffic to your site is originating, you're going to have to ask the user directly unless you work directly with Facebook on some type of integration.